# Calculations on data frames in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I have a list of data frames:

```
str(Test) 
List of 3
$ A:'data.frame':   32400 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ X : num [1:32400] -0.0152 -0.0302 -0.0453 -0.0604 -0.0755 ...
  ..$ Y : num [1:32400] 0.00875 0.01745 0.02615 0.0349 0.0436 ...
  ..$ Z : num [1:32400] -1 -0.999 -0.999 -0.998 -0.996 ...
  ..$ Ts: num [1:32400] 0.000427 0.001696 0.003805 0.006765 0.010537 ...
 $ B:'data.frame':  32400 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ X : num [1:32400] -0.0153 -0.0305 -0.0457 -0.061 -0.0763 ...
  ..$ Y : num [1:32400] 0.00848 0.01692 0.02536 0.03384 0.04228 ...
  ..$ Z : num [1:32400] -1 -0.999 -0.999 -0.998 -0.996 ...
  ..$ Ts: num [1:32400] 0.000427 0.001696 0.003805 0.006765 0.010537 ...
 $ C:'data.frame':  32400 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ X : num [1:32400] -0.0155 -0.0308 -0.0462 -0.0616 -0.077 ...
  ..$ Y : num [1:32400] 0.00822 0.01638 0.02455 0.03277 0.04094 ...
  ..$ Z : num [1:32400] -1 -0.999 -0.999 -0.998 -0.996 ...
  ..$ Ts: num [1:32400] 0.000427 0.001696 0.003805 0.006765 0.010537 ...
```

I want to create two new columns in each dataframe. The new values are based on `X`, `Y`, `Z` of each dataframe:

```
new_x = sqrt(2/(1-Z)) * X

new_y = sqrt(2/(1-Z)) * Y
```

I have tried a few things (and read a lot) and this is what I think should work:

```
t=function(x){
new_x = sqrt(2/(1-x[,3])) * x[,1]
new_y = sqrt(2/(1-x[,3])) * x[,2] }

New_Test=lapply(Test, within, t)
```

However, this only creates a new `list` that is exactly like the old `list`. 
I have tried to use `mapply` and looked into the `plyr` package but could not find a solution. I am fairly new to `R` so be kind ;-)

Edit: Both solutions posted below work! Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Not entirely related, but I would advise against naming a variable "list" because list is a base r function.

Comment: try `x$new_x = ...` within your function `t`. Right now you are not assigning anything as far as I can see.

Comment: can you post the results of `dput(Test)`?

Comment: Something like `Test2 <- lapply(Test, function(df) {df$new_x <- sqrt(2/(1-df$Z)) * df$X; df$new_y <- sqrt(2/(1-df$Z)) * df$Y; return(df)})` is likely to work.

Comment: @Buckminster 's code gets me new colums (called new_x and new_y, however the values are exactly the same as in X and Y. Which is strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fully implementation of the suggestion I made in the comments.

First we simulate some data:

```
listOfDataframes<- list( 
        df1 = data.frame(X = runif(100), Y = runif(100), Z = runif(100)),
        df2 = data.frame(X = runif(100), Y = runif(100), Z = runif(100)),
        df3 = data.frame(X = runif(100), Y = runif(100), Z = runif(100))
)
```

Then we write a function to perform the desire operation. Note that the use of `return` is unnecessary and only included for clarity.

```
yourFun <- function(df) {
        df$new_x <- sqrt(2/(1-df$Z)) * df$X
        df$new_y <- sqrt(2/(1-df$Z)) * df$Y
        return(df) # just "df" would produce the same result 
}
```

Then we apply the function to your list of data.frames and assign the result to a new list:

```
newList <- lapply(listOfDataframes, yourFun)
```

Finally, we display the first few entries of every dataframe to verify our results.

```
lapply(newList, head)
$df1
          X          Y          Z     new_x     new_y
1 0.7122989 0.85574735 0.26176397 1.1724104 1.4085198
2 0.8373206 0.18083472 0.19733040 1.3217167 0.2854489
3 0.6780758 0.76722834 0.48987088 1.3426203 1.5191462
4 0.3694669 0.42579811 0.10287797 0.5516515 0.6357597
5 0.1466816 0.69924651 0.08006688 0.2162781 1.0310202
6 0.3280546 0.06574292 0.22372561 0.5265669 0.1055252

$df2
          X          Y         Z    new_x      new_y
1 0.9385518 0.50570095 0.3062779 1.593604 0.85864969
2 0.6672409 0.66002494 0.3721208 1.190857 1.17797831
3 0.7559528 0.73025591 0.4063969 1.387591 1.34042338
4 0.1960170 0.01639017 0.9700715 1.602382 0.13398487
5 0.9336734 0.76437690 0.3301318 1.613301 1.32077206
6 0.7320958 0.03640788 0.1761000 1.140632 0.05672482

$df3
           X         Y         Z     new_x     new_y
1 0.45050818 0.9843507 0.8956288 1.9720924 4.3089794
2 0.32775145 0.1385610 0.9713440 2.7381165 1.1575725
3 0.07208382 0.8635344 0.5244027 0.1478200 1.7708221
4 0.50439997 0.1328935 0.5827728 1.1043424 0.2909594
5 0.46265459 0.3394566 0.4912585 0.9173252 0.6730551
6 0.15894944 0.4517309 0.3610197 0.2812097 0.7991919
```